# Why is the CSV file not being emptied before rewriting even after calling `file.truncate()`?

Tags: python, file-io

I'm writing a program that reads from a database and puts the contents into a .txt document. Because I don't want this .txt to be huge, I delete all the contents with the `file.truncate()` method before rewriting the rows. However, the file just grows larger and larger each time I run the script.

```
import rethinkdb as rt
import csv
import datetime as dt
import time

#EXAMPLE LOCAL IP FOR THE SAKE OF POSTING
rt.connect("0.0.0.0").repl()


date = dt.datetime.now()

updates = {'Object A':0,'Object B':0}

while True:
    for code in updates:
        prev = {}
        query = list(rt.db("test").table("table").filter(rt.row["Name"][:len(code)+1] == code + ' ').run())
        try:
            # IF TEXT FILE EXISTED ALREADY, READ THE FILE
            with open(code + '{:02d}'.format(date.year) + '{:02d}'.format(date.month) + '{:02d}'.format(date.day) + '.txt',"r+",newline='') as file:
                reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter='\t')
                writer = csv.writer(file, delimiter='\t')
                print('prev len1: '+ str(len(prev)))
                prev = {row[0]:row[1] for row in reader}
                
                file.truncate()
                
                for item in query:
                    try:
                        if item['Counter'] < prev[item['Name']]:    # THE KEYERROR THAT THE TRY BLOCK IS TRYING TO CATCH WOULD BE RAISED IN THIS LINE
                            prev[item['Name']] = prev[item['Name']] + item['Counter']
                        else:
                            prev[item['Name']] = item['Counter']
                    except KeyError:
                        prev[item['Name']] = item['Counter']
                
                    writer.writerow([item['Name'],prev[item['Name']]])
               
        except:
            # IF TEXT FILE FOR THE DAY DOESN'T EXIST, CREATE A NEW FILE
            with open(code + '{:02d}'.format(date.year) + '{:02d}'.format(date.month) + '{:02d}'.format(date.day) + '.txt',"w",newline='') as file:
                for item in query:
                    writer = csv.writer(file,delimiter='\t')
                    writer.writerow([item['Name'],item['Counter']])
        
        file.close()

    print('Updated...')
    time.sleep(30)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are opening the file for reading and appending ("r+") and then you read the file. The file pointer advances to the end of the file. When you truncate the file, you truncate at that point.

You must put the file pointer to the beginning of the file before the `truncate` command:

```
file.seek(0)
```

Alternatively, you can simply use the only parameter accepted by `truncate`, the size of truncation:

```
file.truncate(0)
```

Comment: Thanks! file.truncate(0) doesn't really work, for each even loop it copies again the data and I see some blank lines at the start of the file (like 10-15 lines), but in the odd loops it actually cleans the file and puts the data as if it were a new file. Including file.seek(0) and not passing an argument for truncate works for me though, so thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

`file.truncate` [according the manual](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.truncate) does this:

> Truncate the file’s size. If the optional size argument is present, 
>   the file is truncated to (at most) that size. The size defaults  to
>   the **current** position…

So you need to supply argument `size=0`:

```
file.truncate(size=0)
```

Comment: Thanks! Setting the argument to 0 doesn't work for me (explained in the answer below), but including file.seek(0) does the trick :)